# why my drawpoint function doesn't works good?

Tags: c++, opengl

I'm beginner at open GL and in my code, when status is 3 code works good but when status is 1, it cannot draw line. I want to connect two points with a line.
please help me how can I fix my `if(status==1)` statement to draw a line.
this is my code:

```
    void myMouse(int button, int state, int x, int y)
    {
        if(button==GLUT_LEFT_BUTTON && state==GLUT_DOWN)
        {
            if (((x>=30 && x<=70) && ((wh-y)>=400 && (wh-y)<=440)))
                status=1;//draw line
            else if((x>=30 && x<=70) && ((wh-y)>=280 && (wh-y)<=320))
                status=2;
            else if((x>=30 && x<=70) && ((wh-y)>=520 && (wh-y)<=560))
                status=3;//clear page
            else if((x>=30 && x<=70) && ((wh-y)>=160 && (wh-y)<=200))
                status=4;
            else if((x>=30 && x<=70) && ((wh-y)>=40 && (wh-y)<=80))
                status=5;
            else drawPoint(x,y);
        }
    }
void drawPoint(int x,int y)
{
        if(status==1)
        {
            glBegin(GL_LINES);
            glVertex2i(x,y);
            //glVertex2i(x,y);
            glEnd();
            glFlush();
        }

        if(status==3){
            glClear(GL_COLOR_BUFFER_BIT);
            glFlush();
        }

        else{
        y=wh-y;
        glBegin(GL_POINTS);
        glVertex2i(x,y);
        glEnd();
        glFlush();}
}
```

Comment: if the question is not clear, add a comment first. if it's already was not clear for you, then give minus point!!!!

Comment: "my function doesn't works good" is not an acceptably scientific problem statement.

Comment: You're specifying only one vertex for the line. A line needs two vertices.

Comment: @RetoKoradi do you test it with to vertices? does it work?

Comment: if you suggest a solution, test it yourself at first!!!!

Comment: Since you are seeking for help here, you should try to keep your comments constructive. Reto Koriadi is one of the most helpful people around here.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

you can also check the status conditions in the function `myMouse()`. then you can get new points and store them in the two-dimensional array.
if you store x and y in the array, you can access to the previous points and then you can plot a line.

```
if(status==1)
        {
            glBegin(GL_LINES);
            glVertex2i(arrx[i],arry[j]);
            glVertex2i(arrx[I-1],arry[j-1]);
            glEnd();
            glFlush();
        }
```

Answer (score 0):

The default visible range in OpenGL is from [-1 to 1] on each axis. It looks as if x and y are specified in pixel coordinates which requires you to use a projection matrix (most probably a orthographic one). The code will look somehow like this:

```
glMatrixMode(GL_PROJECTION);
glOrtho(0, width, height, 0, 0, 1);
```

In addition you will still need a second point for the line (as told by Reto Koradi). And I don't know if this is intended, but the else branch will also be executed when status is 1.